# How to create flying floating custom list items

Tags: android

Is there a control that achieves what's in the picture? example would be appreciated. In my case I'm using a custom listview with custom adapter, and I want to achieve what's in the picture.

I'm targeting Android 4.1+ (API 17 and forward)

[image]

P.S: The picture is the Opened Apps History list on Android Lollipop, I don't want to create a floating window (One Card / One Item), I want my items in a list to appear in a cool way as in the picture. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a floating custom list item, it is **FloatingWindow** . You can use to following link to implement your idea.
**Try this one :**

https://github.com/klinker24/FloatingWindowDemo

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but I want create a list of items that has such cool effect as the apps history in Lollipop, not a floating window.